# Backbone switch between different views and domReady functions do not work

Tags: backbone.js, document, document-ready

In my application I am using backbone views for different pages like users, tasks, calendar etc by using backbone router I am switching from one view(e.g Taskview) to another view(say calendar view). everything works fine except dom ready function don't work after I switch the view. 
Backend of my application is in laravel so I have a common laravel view for all pages and I am just switching backbone views without any page refresh. My dom ready functions work one time after page refresh but if I switch to another view they stop working.
Note: Dom ready functions  are linked to view template classes and id's. All view's have similar templates and similar id's. But when I switch views I remove the old view and appends new view along with its templates. 
Any ideas how can I get these working. for document ready I am using domready from require.js

Answer (score 1):

You might be misunderstanding what `$( document ).ready()` is.

> $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

And Since You are making SPA(single page application) which control DOM to change page and never move to another html file.So $( document ).ready() only get fired once.

Backbone.js fires "route" event when Backbone changes page.

> "route" (router, route, params) — Fired by history (or router) when
>   any route has been matched.

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Events-catalog

```
yourMainController.listenTo(yourRouter,"route", function(route, params) {
    console.log("move to " + route);
});
```

You can use the event instead.